# JHipster changes in HTML are not effective

Tags: java, html, css, intellij-idea, jhipster

my question is about a little problem with changes in Jhipster. I've created a project and imported it to intellij idea. After that I tried to make some changes in the "home.components.html" file. That is the file, which is shown wenn you open the app as a localhost. I tried to run the app after the changes,  but the changes aren't shown. For example i changed the h1 tag in this file, from "Welcome Java Hipster" to "ABC".

What can i do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you running both yarn and maven/gradle. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293111/jhipster-maven-and-yarn-execution/47295576#47295576

Answer (score 0):

Run `yarn start` in a new terminal (or cmd if you are a Windows user).

As soon as you modify one of your HTML/CSS/TypeScript file, your browser will refresh itself automatically

More info: http://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with yarn start and the browser is refreshing after i made some changes and saved them. but in the browser the changes are not shown ...

Comment: Which URL do you open in your browser to access your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using i18n, you need to make your changes in those files, not in the HTML.